# easy_install runs with older python version

Tags: python, easy-install

I have isntalled python2.7 to CentOS6.4 which default python version 2.6.

All library and binary links are properly done and I also set alias in bash_profile to run python2.7 default when I write python to command line.

But when I do `easy_install pip` it still installs it to python2.6/site-packages

How can I fix it to install packages to python2.7?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Install easy_install against Python 2.7.

```
python2.7 setup.py install
```